# CSS Position Fixed - Scroll Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, css-position

At present I had a static header, now it is static. I am using this js (found on CSS-Tricks):

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
          // Set Scroll Speed Below
        }, 800);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

It basically scroll based if the a link contains an href.

However when on mobile width (using a media query). I have set the header to:

```
position:static
```

From:

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
```

I what I am asking is the header (which is 60px, a scss variable), cuts off the first 60px of the section of the page because it is set to "top:0;", is there anyway to get the scrolling effect of the JS above but have the ability to -60px scroll prior hitting the anchor.

Either based a list of comma separated id's or addition classes within the HTML document or specific JS.

I would note that I do not want the minus scroll when on mobile as the header is positioned statically at the top.

Comment: why not add 60px padding to the top section in your media query or can that not be done with scss?

Comment: Because I have a background image, the id is at the top level of the section block. I would have to re-gut all the html and css.